# Seleccionar fecha de input y sumarle días a esa fecha a partir de otra variable (PHP, mysql y javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo una tabla dentro de un formulario con 3 campos:
El campo `-Días del pago-` trae desde la base de datos la cantidad de días.

No encuentro la forma de seleccionar la `-Fecha de Salida-` y a esa fecha sumarle los -Días del pago- y que en el ultimo campo que se llama `-Fecha de pago-` me traiga la `-Fecha de salida-` más los `-Días del pago-`.

El problema es que no se como hacer en `javascript` para que se haga automáticamente en la misma pantalla.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><font color="#0f0f0f">Fecha de Salida:</font></td>
    <td><input name="fecha_sali" id="fecha_sali" type="date" style="height:35px;width:200px;font-size:1em;" size="25"></td>
  </tr>  
<tr>
    <td><font color="#000">Días del Pago:</font></td>
    <td><input name="pago" id="pago" type="text" value="<?php echo $terms_p; ?>" style="height:35px;width:200px;font-size:1em;" size="25"></td>
</select>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td><font color="#000">Fecha de pago:</font></td>
    <td><input name="pago" id="pago" type="date" style="height:35px;width:200px;font-size:1em;" size="25"></td>
</select>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td><font color="#000">Embarque:</font></td>
    <td><select name="estado" style="width:200px;border:1px solid #04467E;border-radius:10px;background-color:#DDFFFF;color:#2D4167;font-size:18px" required>
     <option></option>
     <option value="1">Completo</option>
     <option value="PARCIAL">Parcial</option>
</select>
</tr>
</table>
```

Cualquier ayuda seria estupenda muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utiliza ajax para obtener la información de tu base, no se si los días de pago dependen de algún dato?

```
ejemplo:
var  datos= $('#fecha_sali').val();
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{"datos":datos},
            // Formato de datos que se espera en la respuesta
            //dataType: "json",
            url:"obtenDiasPago.php",
            success:function(r){
               //r trae los dias de pago
               var res;//aqui puedes hacer la operación y asignarle a res
               $('#diaspago').val(res);
               $('#fechapago').val(res);


            }
        });
```

espero que sea de tu ayuda

Comment: Hola, los días de pago depende del usuario registrado, dependiendo del usuario los días pueden ser 60 o 45 o 30 o 7.

Comment: Con ajax puedo traer la información en la misma ventana?  ejemplo solo selecciono la fecha de salida y automaticamente sumarle a esa fecha los dias del pago.

Comment: ajax te permite hacer peticiones al backend sin recargar la pagina

Comment: Pero igual no me sirvio el ejemplo Juan.

Comment: Igualmente muchas grcias Juan, muy amable de tu parte. saludos